# Cloudflare forward URL page rule from subdomain to root domain for all routes not working

Tags: redirect, cloudflare, forwarding

I created a Cloudflare page rule that would forward `https://www.example.com/` to `https://example.com/` using these expressions from this documentation: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules. The forwarding does work for the `/` route but if the user were to type the URL `https://www.example.com/first` it would redirect the client to `https://example.com/`. It should be directing the client to `https://example.com/first`. These are the expressions I used from the documentation I mentioned but they don't seem to be working:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need $2 i.e. redirect to `https://example.com/$2`. Your current setup should be redirecting `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com/www`

The pattern matching in cloudflare will match each asterisk in the pattern. If the pattern is `https://*.example.com/*` and you request `https://www.example.com/somepath` then $1 will equal `www` and $2 will equal `somepath`.

Comment: Why did you put `www` after the url? Is that supposed to be an example of a route? And why `$2` over `$1`? What's the difference between these two?

Comment: I have updated my answer to give a better explanation.

Comment: Your explanation helped out thanks. I actually changed the pattern to be `www.example.com/*` so using `$1` does work. It redirects to `https://example.com/$1`.